Can HPLC detection change with the filtration of the sample knowing that the compound of interest is in both solid and liquid phases?
I have run a nitrosamination reaction. It is biphasic (amine solubility is limited). Waited for days and collected good kinetics data for the liquid phase. I know the nitrosamine is also in the solid phase (slurry) but the peak doesn't show up in HPLC although it clearly shows up in the liquid phase samples. Made 500 % sure that all my samples were taken properly such as all dissolved well in the diluent. I know nitrosamine is in the solid phase too because at the end of the ~ 13 days I filtered the biphasic mixture. Took samples from the solid and ran NMR. The nitrosamine was there clearly after comparing it to the starting material (amine). I also know that the solid gets fluffy when nitrosamine forms and precipitates, so visually I could see that nitrosamine was forming and precipitating out. It was a mixture of amine and nitrosamine slurry as the reaction went on. What could be the reason that I see the product (nitrosamine( peak only in the liquid phase (filtered) samples while it is clearly in both phases? I must say that I see the amine peak clearly in the slurry samples so the chromatogram looks normal, it is just that I am missing the nitrosamine peak when I take the slurry sample and dissolve in the diluent directly.

Please clarify your question, clearly think about the steps. Is your analyte solid or a liquid,  what is the meaning of "I know the nitrosamine is also in the solid phase (slurry)". What are the other solids? Can you post chromatograms, mobile phase, detection methods etc. A lot of relevant information is missing.

Analyte is liquid and it is a heterogeneous system. The poorly soluble amine dissolves and reacts in the liquid phase and then more amine dissolves from the solid phase until its solubility limit. And it continues reacting. I collect samples as they are (slurry) and filter them. Both samples are put in the same diluent which dissolves everything in the slurry samples. May plan was to see the total concentration (slurry samples) at each time and see what is happening only in the liquid phase. I hope this clarifies.
